# Openwrt Script - Autostartup Shadowsocks

Tags: openwrt

I would like to create a script for openwrt that every day changes some variables inside the Shadowsocks service. This is the script but i don't know where to put it or how to manage to call it every day or every reboot of router.

```
#!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common

restart=0
for i in `uci show shadowsocks | grep alias | sed -r 's/.*\[(.*)\].*/\1/'`
do
    server=$(uci get shadowsocks.@servers[${i}].alias)
    result=$(nslookup $server)

    new_ip=$(echo "${result}" | tail -n +3 | awk -F" " '/^Address 1/{ print $3}')
    if [ -n "$new_ip" ]; then
        logger -t shadowsocks "nslookup $server -> $new_ip"
        old_ip=$(uci get shadowsocks.@servers[${i}].server)
        if [ "$old_ip" != "$new_ip" ]; then
            logger -t shadowsocks "detect $server ip address change ($old_ip -> $new_ip)"
            restart=1
            uci set shadowsocks.@servers[${i}].server=${new_ip}
        fi
    else
        logger -t shadowsocks "nslookup $server fail"
    fi
done

if [ $restart -eq 1 ]; then
    logger -t shadowsocks "restart for server ip address change"
        uci commit shadowsocks
    /etc/init.d/shadowsocks restart
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) utility. Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer OS. It allows to run jobs/programs/scripts at specified times.

OpenWrt comes with a cron system by default, provided by busybox.

Cron is not enabled by default, so your jobs won't be run. To activate cron in Openwrt:

```
/etc/init.d/cron start
/etc/init.d/cron enable
```

Ref: https://oldwiki.archive.openwrt.org/doc/howto/cron

Now considering your question, if you want to run mentioned script every day:

Edit cron file using `crontab -e` command. And write below line.

```
0 0 * * * sh /path/to/your/script.sh
```

This command will run your script at 00:00 (every day mid night). You can easily modify the above command to schedule your job at any other time. Good reference to generate cron job entry: https://crontab.guru/

To see if crontab is working properly:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep CRON
```

Now coming to your second question "**Run script at every reboot of router**":

You can put your script in **/etc/rc.local**. This file will be executed as as a shell script on every boot up by /etc/rc.d/S95done in Openwrt. So just edit /etc/rc.local with `sh /path/to/your/script.sh` Make sure your script is executable and doing your task properly.